# Entity Framework - DbSet not being populated properly

Tags: database, entity-framework, seed, seeding

I'm designing a database with Entity Framework code first and trying to seed it with data. Unfortunately the seed data isn't being stored on the database.

Debugging has revealed the problem to be with the DbSet not being populated. Although there are 196 items that need to be added, it's only adding 8 and there doesn't seem to be any pattern that gives me a clue as to why. The others simply aren't being added, even though Add is being called each time (I've also tried it with AddOrUpdate with the same result).

```
        var regionArray = new[]
        {
            new Region {Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Europe" },
            new Region { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Asia" },
            new Region { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "North America" },
            new Region { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "South America" },
            new Region { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Central America" },
            new Region { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Africa" },
            new Region { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Middle East" },
            new Region {Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = "Oceania" }
        };

        var countryArray = new[]
        {
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Russia", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Ukraine", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="France", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Spain", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Sweden", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Norway", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Germany", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Finland", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Poland", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Italy", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="United Kingdom", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Romania", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Kazakhstan", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Greece", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Bulgaria", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Iceland", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Hungary", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Portugal", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Serbia", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Austria", Region = regionArray[0] },
            new Country {Id=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name="Czech Republic", Region = regionArray[0] },
};


        for (int i = 0; i < countryArray.Length; i++)
        {
            AddOrUpdatePreservingCreatedAt(context.Countries, countryArray[i]);
        }
}

private void AddOrUpdatePreservingCreatedAt<T>(DbSet<T> set, T item) where T : EntityData
    {
        var existing = set.Where(i => i.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (existing != null)
        {
            item.CreatedAt = existing.CreatedAt;
        }
        set.Add(item);
    }
```

regionArray has already been seeded successfully to the database. I've only provided a subset of the full countryArray.

Comment: is the correct DbSet<> given? where is this actually called?

Comment: It's in the Configuration class. I'm using Nuget console command Update-Database. It should be the correct DbSet as it is saving 'some' of the content into it. For some reason it's not doing all of them.

Comment: I've done some more investigation and for some reason what seems to be happening is that instead of ADDing a new record to the DbSet, it's replacing the one that's already there.